# iOS – Handle OTP (one-time code) in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextfield, one-time-password

Is there any way to handle onetime-code tap by restricting other keyboard entries?

I have requirement for an OTP text field to prefill the sms OTP code.
User should not enter the OTP manually using keyboard numeric buttons.

IOS 12 we have the onetime-code option, it will be auto-filled in QuickType bar  & User can tap on it to fill the text field.  I Couldn't find an option to restrict other keyboard entries.

Is there any way we can allow only  Onetime code tap and **restricting any entry from the numeric keyboard .**

What I have tried is created 6 textfields. 
First textfield content type set as One Time code.
UserInteractionEnabled only for the first text field so that user can't enter data onto other fields. 
Once I get the OTP & taps QuickType bar - onetime code, I am prefilling all the text fields.

viewdidload>

```
otp1TB.addTarget(self, action:#selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)


@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if let otpCode = textField.text ,  otpCode.count > 5 {
        otp1TB.text = String(otpCode[otpCode.startIndex])
        otp2TB.text = String(otpCode[otpCode.index(otpCode.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)])
        otp3TB.text = String(otpCode[otpCode.index(otpCode.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)])
        otp4TB.text = String(otpCode[otpCode.index(otpCode.startIndex, offsetBy: 3)])
        otp5TB.text = String(otpCode[otpCode.index(otpCode.startIndex, offsetBy: 4)])
        otp6TB.text = String(otpCode[otpCode.index(otpCode.startIndex, offsetBy: 5)])
        otp1TB.isUserInteractionEnabled = false 
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

The issue here is since the first text field is active when the keyboard opens user has the ability to enter numeric data from the keyboard.

I need to allow only onetime code tap when the keyboard opens.

Comment: Can you share some code of what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can skip this entire complexity and just use the standard iOS 12 OTP input type:

```
otpTextField.textContentType = .oneTimeCode
```

See: [Automatic OTP verification in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39631168/1214800)

And the WWDC 2018 video that covers it: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/204

Comment: First text field content type set as One Time Code in storyboard. I am looking for a solution to restrict other keyboard numeric entry.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't very clear in your question - it was hard to follow. Sounds like you want this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53414345/1214800

Comment: I have tried that. No luck with statement "if textField.textContentType == UITextContentType.oneTimeCode"

Comment: OK, then I would suggest rewording your question to make it clear what the problem is you're having, and explain how it relates to the code you've shown.

Comment: Sorry, if it was not clear. I have updated the text

Answer (score 1):

You can try My 3rd party library:-
https://github.com/Datt1994/DPOTPView

**For Solution:-**

In viewDidLoad add tag & delegate to all `textfield`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    otp1TB.delegate = self
    otp1TB.tag = 1000
    otp2TB.delegate = self
    otp2TB.tag = 2000
    otp3TB.delegate = self
    otp3TB.tag = 3000
    otp4TB.delegate = self
    otp4TB.tag = 4000
    otp5TB.delegate = self
    otp5TB.tag = 5000
    otp6TB.delegate = self
    otp6TB.tag = 6000
}
```

In UITextFieldDelegate extension implement `shouldChangeCharactersIn` function like below, It will also work with `textField.textContentType = .oneTimeCode`

```
extension ViewController : UITextFieldDelegate  {

public func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if string.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespaces).count != 0 {
        textField.text = string
        if textField.tag < count*1000 {
            let next = textField.superview?.viewWithTag((textField.tag/1000 + 1)*1000)
            next?.becomeFirstResponder()
        } else if textField.tag == count*1000 {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    } else if string.count == 0 { // is backspace
        textField.text = ""
    }

    return false
}

}
```